# Clean white space from a div's ID attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do you use jQuery to remove whitespace from a div's ID.

So this:

```
<div class="modal" ID="The ID of the Div"></div>
```

Becomes:

```
<div class="modal" ID="TheIDoftheDiv"></div>
```

The reason being I'm setting the ID dynamically from a text string which has spaces.

Comment: It would be much better to remove the spaces from the string *before* you set the `id` value.

Comment: can u share the code with which u are allocation the id name to id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thing would be to create the element with the right `id` in the first place.

Barring that, it breaks down into:

1. Getting the element, and
2. Changing its `id`

This'll work, using an [attribute value selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('[id="The ID of the Div"]').attr("id", "TheIDoftheDiv");
```

Or you can use `document.getElementById`:

```
document.getElementById("The ID of the Div").id = "TheIDoftheDiv";
```

Or if the id will be variable:

```
var theId = "The ID of the Div";
// ...
$('[id="' + theId + '"]').attr("id", theId.replace(/ /g, ''));
```

Or if you're actually going to select the element a different way and it's just the replacing the `id` you're unsure of:

```
var $div = $("...select the element...");
$div[0].id = $div[0].id.replace(/ /g, '');
```

Or if you prefer avoiding variables and using a single overall statement:

```
$('...select the element...').attr("id", function(_, id) {
    return id.replace(/ /g, '');
});
```

Comment: Will this create a problem, if I refer the element with its Id and change the id in its callback function(last code snipet).

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: No. jQuery doesn't dynamically remove it from the set or anything.

Comment: Then when will be the old id become invalid?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: All that changing the `id` does is change the `id`. It has no effect on any reference you have to element object. Separately, jQuery objects aren't "live" collections that update themselves when you change properties on the elements in them. The selector you give initially is just used **then**, to find matching elements. So if you tried to use the old `id` to find the element again, you wouldn't find it, but that has no effect on any references you already have to the element.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: Just for completeness: In the DOM, there *are* "live" collections that behave that way (somewhat): The ones returned by `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByClassName` are "live" -- if you change an element so that it no longer fits in the collection, it's removed from the collection. This doesn't affect any *other* reference you have to the element, but the collection does get updated. This isn't true of jQuery objects, or of the collections you get back from `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Thanks  T.J. Crowder I used $('...select the element...').attr("id", function(_, id) {
    return id.replace(/ /g, '');
}); Works perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
str.replace(" ", "");
```

in id attribute